# Extract the YYYY year from two string columns and put it in a new column, keeping NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

In a dataframe I have two columns with the information of when some football players make their debut.The columns are called 'Debut' and 'Debut Deportivo'. I have to create a function to create a new column with the YYYY year information of both columns keeping the Nan values from both when applied. Let me show and example: [image]

With the code I have wrote until now, I am able to get the value from one column a put it in the new one, but I've never reach the form to combine both.

The result should be something like this:

| Debut | Debut Deportivo | fecha_debut |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27 de mayo de 2006 | 2006(UD Vecindario) | 2006 |
| 21 de agosto de 2010 | 11 de agosto de 2010(Portuguesa) | 2010 |
| 21 de agosto de 2010 | NaN | 2010 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |

Can you help me to get this code right please

````
    df_4['Debut deportivo'].fillna('0000',inplace=True)
    df_4['Debut'].fillna('0000', inplace=True)
    def find_year(x):
        año = re.search('\d{4}', x)
        return int(año.group(0)) if año else 0
    df_4['fecha_debut'] = df_4['Debut'].map(find_year)
    df_4['fecha_debut'] = df_4 ['Debut deportivo'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x.find('2')==-1  else x[x.find('0')-1:x.find('(')])
    df_4['club_debut'] = df_4 ['Debut deportivo'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x.find ('(')==-1  else x[x.find('(')+1:x.find(')')])
    df_4['fecha_debut'] = df_4['fecha_debut'].replace(0,np.nan)
    # No modifiques las siguientes lineas 
    assert(isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame))
    return df```
````

Comment: When you say "[extract] the information of both columns", do you want the date as a `pd.DateTime` (MM/DD/YYYY) but the year as an `int`? Or both as strings? Or just both years as ints? (it's in general desirable to store dates as datetimes, because then they work with comparisons, sorting, ordering etc.)

Comment: I needed only the year as an int

Comment: Ok then please click Edit above on your question and edit that missing information in (that you only want to extract the 4-digit YYYY, in this case 20YY). It would have totally wasted my time if I'd written you an answer showing you how to parse into a datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) + [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html#pandas.Series.combine_first)

```
df['fecha_debut'] = df['Debut'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})').combine_first(df['Debut Deportivo'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})'))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                  Debut                   Debut Deportivo fecha_debut
0    27 de mayo de 2006               2006(UD Vecindario)        2006
1  21 de agosto de 2010  11 de agosto de 2010(Portuguesa)        2010
2  21 de agosto de 2010                               NaN        2010
3                   NaN                               NaN         NaN
```

For more on how to work with strings in pandas see [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html).

**UPDATE**

If you need the column to be numeric you could do:

```
df['fecha_debut'] = pd.to_numeric(df['fecha_debut']).astype(pd.Int32Dtype())
```

Note that because you have missing values in the column it cannot be of type int32. It can be either [nullable integer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) or float. For more on working with missing data see [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data).

Comment: it works, but dtype needs to be an int32, what can I add to change that and keep the NaN values?

Comment: What needs to be an int32? fecha_debut?

Comment: yes, fecha_debut needs to be an int32 at the end, we can use a workaround like now we have the values ok do something to change all that to numeric or something like that